# Escaping single quote on SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Hello I am going through some SQL injection examples and I have the following scenario:

In this example, aware of the risk of SQL injection, the developer decided to block single quotes ' by removing any single quote ' in the query. However, there is still a way to break out of the SQL syntax and inject arbitrary SQL.

To do so, you need to think of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='[username]' and password='[password]'
```

The problem here is that you cannot, in theory, break out of the single quotes ' since you cannot inject any quote. However, if you inject a back-slash \, the second ' in the query (the one supposed to finish the string [username] will be escaped and will be closed by the third one (the one supposed to start the string [password].

Doesn't this mean that if I input a "\" on the username field it will automatically break the query? and look something like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='[username] and password=' ..
```

Am I missing something ? Should I provide the backslash in another way?

Comment: Are you asking how to inject sql or how to protect yourself from sql injection attacks?

Comment: how to inject it not how to protect

Comment: To be honest, you should use parameters to pass the values for username and password. You should avoid building a string with values from user input and execute that against your database - that is the 1st step protecting against sql injection.

Comment: I am not looking to protect against, I am looking to complete the exercise and understand how "\" escapes characters, because at the moment it seems it doesn't

Comment: So you are looking for this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx

Answer (score -3):

Ok I have found the answer:
The username should be : \
and password : or 1#
Then the query will look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '\' AND password=' or 1#
```

Comment: A backslash does not escape anything in (standard) SQL. That simply looks for a user with the name `\ `  and `or 1#` is invalid SQL to begin with